# How to delete a pointer after cast to void* and back

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, delete-operator, void-pointers

As part of a "message"-class I try to transfer pointers of different types by casting them to void*-pointers and saving them in a wrapper class ("MsgData") that remembers the original type of the pointer.

For example a bool pointer:

```
bool* data = new bool;
event.wheel.y < 0 ? *data = false : *data = true;
send("all", this, MSG_MOUSE_SCROLL, MsgData(data));
```

The compatible Constructor of MsgData is called and the variable is saved as a member of my message class:

```
MsgData():                        type_(NULLPTR),    data_(nullptr)     {}  // Null
MsgData(const bool* data):        type_(BOOL),       data_((void*)data) {}  // Bool
MsgData(const std::string* data): type_(STRING_STD), data_((void*)data) {}  // std::string
// ... etc.
```

I can cast the pointers back and use them without any errors but when I try to delete them the program crashes:

```
~MsgData() {
    switch (type_) {
    case (BOOL):
        if ((bool*)data_)
            delete (bool*)data_;
        break;
    // ... etc.
    }
}
```

The bool pointer is just an example and the same happens with all other types and classes too.
The program crashes only when I try to delete the pointer. Casting them back to their original type and using them is not a problem.

I researched the problem and found similar question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772699/how-to-delete-void-pointer/24772756) on StackOverflow but while it seems to be considered bad style to cast a pointer to void* and back I cannot find the reason why the program crashes.

Comment: One thing I would like to note is that you should be using `static_cast` in C++ code to make your intent more obvious.

Comment: Why dont you use `boost::variant`?

Comment: Or `std::variant`.

Comment: Your approach should work. We can't help without a [mcve].

Comment: In order to debug your code, we need to see it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Never really used boost and if it is possible I would like to solve the problem without extra libraries to keep the program as simple as possible. But I'll definitely have a look at it.

Comment: You can even use `std::any` to allow almost any data without having to do this overloading and type list code. You gain performance, flexibility *and* type safety.

Comment: I'd say using a `variant` type keeps the program simpler than rolling your own. If you don't want Boost and don't have access to the standard one, there's still `mpark::variant`, which acts exactly like the standard one, but is usable without C++17 and is a standalone library.

Comment: If you really want to debug this (which is unnecessary because you should just replace it with something sane instead) print out the type and address of everything you `new` and `delete` and then check the log where it did not match. Alternatively if you are on linux pass `-fsanitize=undefined,address` to have this type of error analyzed at runtime.

Comment: @Mathis Please read [mcve].

Comment: Your code could crash due to any number of reasons entirely unrelated to what you concluded the problem was. The fact that the program reliably crashes in `delete` can be explained by other causes, such as memory corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a better solution to the problem is to use `boost::variant` (or `std::variant`). Once you start using that, all the headache of deleting and managing *type* and *data* will go automatically. You're not the first to face of a problem of this kind; many others have faced it, and the solution is available in the form of `boost::variant` or `std::variant`.

Anyway, since you're developing a solution yourself, here is my advise: construct an appropriate *deleter* in the constructor itself .. or whenever  you know what *type* of *data* your class is going to hold:

```
MsgData()
 : type_(NULLPTR), data_(nullptr)     {} 

MsgData(const bool* data)
 : type_(BOOL), data_((void*)data), deleter_(&deleter<BOOL>) {}      

MsgData(const std::string* data)
 : type_(STRING_STD), data_((void*)data), deleter_(&deleter<std::string>) {}
```

where `deleter_` is a member:

```
std::function<void(void const*)>  deleter_;
```

and `deleter` is defined as function template:

```
template<typename T>
void deleter(void const * data) {
   delete static_cast<T const *>(data);
}
```

Once you have these, your destructor would look like this:

```
~MsgData() {
   if (deleter_) {
      deleter_(data_);
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.